# ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk (a number e.g. 5675) failed

Tags: reactjs, next.js, error-handling, jsx, next.js13

Need help from you.

I have an nextjs app running on vps server. Everything's running good but sometimes getting error "loading chunk (a number as, 6544) failed....". And it's mainly occuring on safari. For that, the whole site or a page gets affected and blank.
Nextjs version is 13.5.4

I have deleted .next build folder, rebuild.

If anyone here help me on this matter, please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.